# How to quantify the similarity of spatial patterns?

Tags: raster, point, spatial-statistics, statistics, similarity

I am not a GISer, but I do believe a GIS (more specifically, spatial statistics) algorithm could help with the task I am carrying on. If posting a question that has already been posted (by me) on stackoverflow here does break the rule, I would delete this question.

I have several 10000*10000 grids (raster data) denoting the same tissue in mice, each representing the expression pattern of a specific type of gene (each grid-point has a value between 0 and 100). The task I am working on now is to quantify the similarity between each spatial expression patterns of genes. Since I want to take spatial information into account, I am thinking about either applying image similarity comparison algorithms from image processing (or computer vision), or spatial similarity comparison algorithms from GIS (spatial statistics). Among the two I believe spatial statistics might be more appropriate.

Sample images:
[image: Sample grid image]

Please refer to my original question on stackoverflow for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912256/how-do-i-quantify-the-similarity-of-spatial-patterns

Comment: I was wondering if you found a solution to your problem. It appears that most folks respond to this issue by employing bivariate LISA maps to assess areas by dichotomous high-low categories. For you, you'll need to first convert your rasters to polygon features (tool in ArcGIS). Then download GeoDA. But there's gotta be something better... I'd like to be able to say something like, "60% of the spatial variation of X can be explained by the spatial variation of Y." Sounds like Geographic Weighted Regression, but not quite.